# PHP Pause Script If internet Connection is lost

Tags: php, download, connection, pause

Im creating a page downloading script fed by A database, and sometimes the internet connection will go, is they're anyway to pause the script while the internet is down and continue when its back online?

Comment: The script is run server side, so it will finish either way if the request reached your server... The problem is the user will never receive an answer since the connection was dropped..

Comment: Mine is a long running script running on a Cron Job, I want to pause it if connection is lost

Comment: It's a cron job, meaning you never use the internet connection, and stay inside your own server, unless you make calls outside your server from within your script?!

Comment: Yes im downloading pages from other servers sorry i thought I explained that, never mind anyways im downloading external pages and its from a list so I need my script to pause when the internet goes down

Comment: One could argue that you could for each iteration of downloaded file, check if a connection is present, if not - sleep 5 seconds and try again. Resume downloading if a connection is present.

Comment: That was my first Idea, but I wanted to know if they're was some faster method for checking that

Comment: Faster than what? You haven't shown what you tried?